# refresh web page without using body onload

Tags: javascript

Hi have a webpage which geolocates a location using javascript, i have set this up so that every time the page refreshes the visitors location is updated.

What i wanted to do was to use a javascript refresh to update the details every three minutes, however i already have a body onload as shown below in my web page.

```
<body onload="getLocation()">
```

Is there another way i can refresh a webpage without the need for javascript to be added to body onload or is there a way i can add both?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the http refresh method. The URL is optional if it is just refreshing the page.

<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30; ,URL=http://www.metatags.org/login">
</head>

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function(){ getLocation(); },12345)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.setInterval(functionToCall, timeIntervalInMilis);